# MS word custom caption labels are missing

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

I'm using MS word 2016. I have word document in which I had created custom labels for captioning figures, tables, etc. But after a while they are all disappeared. Is there a way to bring them back?

I've tried re-creating them, it didn't work.

Comment: Please add more details about what exactly you're doing. As it is your question is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

### You will need to recreate them.

What that takes is to use the same term. I believe it is case sensitive.

You can look at the term as used in prior captions using the custom label. If needed, toggle display of the number in a caption to see what label is used in the SEQ field. You can do that with **Shift+F9** when the number is selected.

Caption labels are not stored with the document but rather on the computer.